# gcc, uninitialized global variables

Tags: c, gcc

Is there any way to know / warn if a global variable is uninitialized with gcc ?

I got it for local/ atomic variables “-Wuninitialized”

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No!
Global and static variables are initialized implicitly if your code doesn't do it explicitly as mandated by the C standard.
In short, global and static variables are never left uninitialized.

Comment: Yes by default. I want them to be initialized explicitly. Any static analyzer should also be fine.

Comment: @AUZKamath: No.Since the standard already mandates global vars to be default initialized gcc doesn't provide warnings or diagnostic for uninitialized global vars.

Answer (score 6):

> **6.9.2 External object definitions**
>
> **Semantics**
>
> **1** If the declaration of an identifier for an object has file scope and an initializer, the
>   declaration is an external definition for the identifier.
>
> **2** A declaration of an identifier for an object that has file scope without an initializer, and
>   without a storage-class specifier or with the storage-class specifier static, constitutes a
>   tentative definition. If a translation unit contains one or more tentative definitions for an
>   identifier, and the translation unit contains no external definition for that identifier, then
>   the behavior is exactly as if the translation unit contains a file scope declaration of that
>   identifier, with the composite type as of the end of the translation unit, with an initializer
>   equal to 0.

The above two clauses (from the standard) guarantee that file-scope (global) objects are always initialized.

Answer (score 3):

No, because gcc automatically initializes all global and static variables to "0".

Comment: Not just gcc. See other answers.