# Why won't gcc compile uninitialized global const?

Tags: gcc, g++, global-variables

When I try to compile the following with g++:

```
const int zero;

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

I get an error about an `uninitialized const 'zero'`. I thought that global variables were default initialized to 0 [1] ? Why isn't this the case here?
VS compiles this fine.

[1] For example, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10927293/331785

Comment: I just realized that `gcc` does compile it. It is `g++` that doesn't. Why is that? Is the rule about global variables being initialized to 0 not part of the c++ standard?

Comment: [Some argue](http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/fqa.html#fqa-21.1) than in C++ random things compile and other random things don't. I don't think even the reference to the standard gives any idea on *why* it should be disallowed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My gcc is slightly more verbose:

```
$ g++ zeroconst.c
zeroconst.c:1:11: error: uninitialized const ‘zero’ [-fpermissive]
```

We see that `-fpermissive` option will allow this to compile.

See this question on [uninitialized const](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092670/uninitialized-const) for a reference to C++ standard (the problem is C++-specific).

As cited at [GCC wiki](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/VerboseDiagnostics#error:_uninitialized_const_.27d.27_.5B-fpermissive.5D.2C_note:_.27const_class_D.27_has_no_user-provided_default_constructor):

> As mandated by the C++ standard (8.5 [decl.init], para 9 in C++03,
>   para 6 in C++0x), G++ does not allows objects of const-qualified type
>   to be default initialized unless the type has a user-declared default
>   constructor. Code that fails to compile can be fixed by providing an
>   initializer...

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't explain why it is even an error under the default configuration. It seems perfectly legal since global variables *are* initialized!

Comment: @baruch added link to a question with the answer quoting the `C++` standard (as of C, it is valid and it compiles)

Answer (score -1):

G++ requires that you initialize your constant during definition.