# No Match for 'operator' error in C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cassert>
#include <ctime>
#include <map>

using namespace std;


struct SBLnode {
    string name;
    SBLnode *next;
    SBLnode * left, * right;
};

struct Queue {
    SBLnode * first, * last;
};

typedef SBLnode* BST;


struct SBL {
    Queue q;
    BST root;
};

void SBL_init (SBL& sbl) {

    sbl = NULL;

}
```

I keep getting the following error in `GCC` when compiling...

```
error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘SBL’ and ‘long int’)
  sbl = NULL;
      ^
```

This error basically is for the line `sbl = NULL` and it would be great if someone could explain to me exactly what that error actually means.

Comment: SBL isn't a pointer, so `NULL` isn't a valid value for it. Instead, each member should recursively be initialized to an appropriate value.

Comment: So in the main function SBL is already created? Do we have access to it's member values? Don't we first need to initialize SBL to something? To have access to it's members. Should that just be created on the stack?

Comment: What's passed in must be initialized in some way (references can't be null), but probably with uninitialized `root` etc. values that need to be changed.

Comment: What if the stuff that's passed in is a reference to a pointer? Wouldn't you then treat the reference as a pointer?

Comment: Then the type of the parameter would be `SBL *&`.

Comment: I'm still a little confused about how I would initialize a reference, and it's values.

Comment: doing something like `sbl.q.first = NULL;`, `sbl.q.last = NULL;`, and finally `sbl.root = NULL;` also gives an error.

Comment: You can use the reference just like the variable. It's effectively the same thing. That should work.

Comment: @user1952811: See my answer. I have your code running with my simple fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can't find the `operator=` for `SBL &SBL::operator=(const long int &rhs)`. There is a better practice. One option is to use a pointer and set it to NULL. NULL evaluates to 0. There is no operator which assigns an `int` intriniscally to your `SBL` struct object.

Or **define a const static instance of the struct with the initial values and then simply assign this value to your variable whenever you want to reset it.**

For example:

```
static const struct SBL EmptyStruct;
```

This uses static initialization to set the initial values.

Then, in `init` you can write:

```
sbl = EmptyStruct;
```

Note: Have to compile with `-fpermissive` in gcc or set `EmptyStruct = { }`. The reason why you have to set `-fpermissive` is listed [here for GCC 4.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14568830/why-wont-gcc-compile-uninitialized-global-const). GCC 4.4 needs `EmptyStruct = { }`.

Here is your program running. Initially it prints "initial" twice and on the third time, it prints empty string. Meaning, it was set to nothing by the assignment in the init function.

```
int main() 
{   
    struct SBLnode initial;
    initial.name = "initial";
    struct Queue q;
    q.first = &initial;
    cout << q.first->name << endl;
    struct SBL testInit;
    testInit.q = q;
    SBL_init(testInit);
    cout << testInit.q.first->name << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/Ecm6I9

Comment: Why is `-fpermissive` needed? That option is probably the last you want to enable.

Comment: @chris: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14568830/why-wont-gcc-compile-uninitialized-global-const

Comment: @chris: I think I assauged your concerns in my edit by setting EmptyStruct = { }, let me know your thoughts

Comment: Oh, just that. Yes, the aggregate initialization should do it.

Answer (score 1):

`NULL` is a macro which expands to the integer literal `0`. There is no intrinsic or user-defined operator which can assign an integer to an object of type `SBL`.

It looks like you are treating `sbl` as a pointer; but it is not a pointer, it is a reference.

You probably wanted to write this instead:

```
void SBL_init (SBL& sbl) {
    sbl.root = NULL;
}
```

This initializes `sbl` by nulling out its member pointers.

As others have commented, `nullptr` is preferred in C++11:

```
void SBL_init (SBL& sbl) {
    sbl.root = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: `left` and `right` are part of `next`. I think you meant `q.first` and `q.last`.

Answer (score 1):

```
void SBL_init (SBL& sbl) {

    sbl = NULL;

}
```

Others have already pointed out why that line doesn't compile.  Perhaps I can suggest an alternative solution.  Instead of providing an init function, why not give all of your structures constructors like so?  Is there some reason that you can't provide those?  The operator= and copy constructor don't need to be defined if shallow copying of pointers is what you want.  Since nodes typically need to be moved around I'm guessing that a shallow copy is fine.  You can certainly use the nullptr if using c++ 11 rather than 0.  I'm not a big fan of the NULL macro and opinions often vary with regards to NULL.

```
struct SBL {
    SBL() : root(0) {}
    Queue q;
    BST root;
};

struct Queue {
    Queue() : first(0), last(0) {}
    SBLnode * first, * last;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This error means that `operator=` , which is a function, is not defined in `struct SBL`. It is required when you write

```
sbl = NULL;
```

Solution:

provide `SBL& operator=( const long int& i);`  in `struct SBL`.

In fact I think that you would like something alike `SBL& operator=( BST b)`:

```
struct SBL {
    Queue q;
    BST root;
    SBL& operator=( BST b) {
      root = b;
      return *this;
    }
};
```

Comment: I disagree with this suggestion.  It's not a very good use of the assignment operator.  An assignment operator should result in all data getting shallow or deep copied.  Since it's not clear what the OP actually wants to do, it is difficult to suggest something in this case, but a partial initialization of an object in an assignment operator is a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

It is trying to find an assignment operator that has the form

```
 SBL &SBL::operator=(const long int &rhs):#
```

and cannot find one.

I guess you were thinking about the pointers.