# Difference between different struct initialization methods

Tags: c++

I understand that there is many different ways to accomplish the same thing in C++; however, I would like to know the differences between these methods of initializing a struct.  I would also like to know what is the C++ way of doing things, as I know some of these methods are from C.

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int x, y, z;
};

MyStruct s1 = { 0 };  //I think this is from C but not really sure.
MyStruct s2 = { }; //I think this might be from C++
MyStruct s3 = { sizeof(MyStruct) } ; //Not sure where this comes from but I like it
```

When programming in C++, which should I use?

Comment: What is the definition of `MyStruct`?

Comment: Just normal data, does it matter?  Lets say 5 int's.

Comment: Can you edit your code with the exact definition, please? It will help us to make sense of your initialization code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Assuming POD types, not the new *uniform-initialization* syntax)

The three are valid initializations in C++ assuming that the struct has a first element that can be initialized from an integer. The third option sets the first member of the struct to the size of the struct, and the rest of the fields are left zero-initialized.

The first two are equivalent in C++, although the second one is not valid C, as in C you must pass at least one value inside the braces.

Answer (score 5):

`MyStruct s3 = { sizeof(MyStruct) } ;` is very unlikely to do what you think it does:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int a;
    int b;
};
```

In this example, `MyStruct s3 = { sizeof(MyStruct) } ;` will initialize `x3.a` to 8 and `x3.b` to 0.

Comment: Oh ok, so its sets the first member to the size of the struct itself?

Comment: Yes, because that's what you told it to do.

Comment: I guess I did, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

[Assuming C++] For s1 , you are initializing the first variable in MyStruct to zero. For s3, you are initializing it to the size of the structure. In both cases, the compiler will convert your supplied value to fit the type of the first-listed variable in MyStruct.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyStruct s1 = { 0 };
```

Using this king of initialization, you will initialize the first element of the structure. If the value do not correspond to the element type, the compiler (gcc or g++ for example) will try to make some implicit cast. All other elements will be set to default value.

```
MyStruct s3 = { sizeof(MyStruct) };
```

is quite the same, the first element value will be the size of the structure in bytes.

```
MyStruct s2 = { };
```

Finally, this initialization is only valid in C++, the equivalent in C is `MyStruct s2;`. It initialize all the value to default.

Answer (score 0):

The first one initializes a structs elements to zero an its pointers to null in C.
http://www.ex-parrot.com/~chris/random/initialise.html and [Initialize/reset struct to zero/null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891720/initialize-reset-struct-to-zero-null)

But does not in C++. In C++ the first element is initialized.

```
MyStruct s1 = { 0 };  //I think this is from C but not really sure.
```

The second one initlializes to zero in C++ , like 1) did for C

```
MyStruct s2 = { };
```

The third sets the first elements value to the sizeof MyStruct in C and in C++

```
MyStruct s3 = { sizeof(MyStruct) } ; //Not sure where this comes from but I like it
```