# Equality with an empty (null-like) struct

Tags: c++, struct

The answer to [the question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891720/initialize-reset-struct-to-zero-null) addresses initializing a null-reset or zero struct.

How can I check equality though?

say my struct x is defined as follows:

```
struct MyStruct {
int a;
int b;

};
```

and the empty struct :

```
static const struct MyStruct EmptyStruct;
```

how do I check equality inside a function that takes a reference to a struct of type x?

```
void myFunction (... , MyStruct &x, ...){
//some code


if (x != EmptyStruct){  // this doesn't work (see error below)


}


//some code
}
```

The error I get when I try the above:

**no match for 'operator!=' in 'x != EmptyStruct'**

**EDIT**: to make it more clear I understand the error message in terms of overloading the != operator for the struct but since an EmptyStruct is a special kind, how can I deal with that?

I guess the point is that a struct of my type with a = 0 and b = 0 is not the same as the EmptyStruct which should represent null-like struct.

Comment: You need to define operator != for type `MyStruct`. This is what the error message is telling you, it cannot find it.

Comment: I get that error message, I am asking for dealing with the empty struct

Comment: This question should not be tagged both `c` and `c++`. The answer is radically different depending on which language you're using. Your error message suggests you're using C++, but some beginners are inadvertently compiling code meant to be C using a C++ compiler, so it's not clear.

Comment: The example you link is C, not C++ - and since you are talking about a `struct` and not a `class` I am beginning to get very confused. Could you please post a small sample program that defines your program and `EmptyStruct` - and that compiles up to the `==` line?

Comment: The first question would be whether you care about *equality* or *identity*. If you care about equality (multiple different objects can be *null* and compare equal), then you will need to find either a value that is out of range to represent *null* or else change and use a different approach (a pointer can be *null*, a reference cannot; an `optional` can be *null*…)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really need to make up your mind whether your `MyStruct` is a value type or an identity type.

If it's a value type, then you want to define some part of its value as saying that it's empty:

```
struct MyStruct { 
    int x;
    int y;

    bool empty;
};
```

If it's an identity type, then you want to check for identity:

```
void myFunction(MyStruct &m) {
    if (&m == &EmptyStruct)
        // reference to EmptyStruct. Act accordingly.
}
```

If you need a singular value like your EmptyStruct, you might want to consider passing a (smart) pointer, and comparing to `nullptr` to determine whether you've received a singular value.

As a general rule, I'd avoid this type of design in general. Identity types are somewhat foreign to most C++ programmers, and singular values create special cases that you're generally better off without.

Comment: So you suggest using the bool empty flag? is that not bad practice?

Comment: @Saher: As I said, I'd avoid this type of design in general. If you insist on doing it anyway, the bool is probably the least bad of the ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to overload the equality operator, testing every element of the structure.

```
bool MyClass::operator==(const MyClass &other) const {
    ...  // Compare the values, and return a bool result.
  }
```

Comment: but EmptyStruct is a special null-like struct it should not have any fields defined.

Comment: in other words a struct of my type with a=0 and b=0 is different from EmptyStruct

Comment: But it is `static`... doesn't that mean it has values in it? What is `sizeof(EmptyStruct)`?

Comment: @Saher: You mean you want to test whether `x` is the same object as `EmptyStruct`? In that case, compare the address, `if (&x == &EmptyStruct)`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply [overload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading) the `operator==` (or `operator!=`). Or (since by default all members of a `struct` are `public`), check all elements inside the structures.

Since your talking something about that your struct is "empty" - there's no such thing. When you create an object, the memory for it should be allocated automatically by the constructor. If you want to check if the passed struct is **the** static `EmptyStruct`, check the addresses of both.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are taking the object by reference, I assume you want to test if the user actually passed the global `EmptyStruct` object as a function argument. This can be achieved easily by comparing addresses:

```
void foo(MyStruct & x)
{
    if (&x == &EmptyStruct) { /* ... */ }
}
```

(This assumes that `MyStruct` does not overload `operator&`.)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to test whether or not `x` refers to the same object as `EmptyStruct`, in which case you want to compare addresses:

```
if (&x != &EmptyStruct)
```

although this is a rather odd thing to do; it usually makes more sense to use a pointer, with a well-defined null value to represent "no object", if you want a nullable reference-like type.

`==` and `!=` are used to compare values, not object identities, and have to be overloaded if you want to define them for class types.